# getting 404 when experimenting with `app.use` and `app.get`

Tags: express

New to `express`. I am trying to test how `app.use` and `app.get` work. From what I understand, `app.use` is a `middleware` i.e. called if I want to do some pre-processing of a request before sending it to main route handler. The main route handler is created using `app.get`

I have written the following code to handle 3 `GET` requests - `/`, `/questions` and `/users`.

app.js

```
...
app.use('/', indexRouter.indexRouter); 
app.use('/question', questionRouter.questionRouter); 
app.use('/users', usersRouter.usersRouter); 
...
```

middleware logic in separate `.js` files is

```
exports.indexRouter = function (req, res, next) {
    router.get('/', index.indexController);
    next();
}

exports.questionRouter = function (req, res, next) {
    router.get('/', question.questionController);
    next();
}
exports.usersRouter = function (req, res, next) {
    router.get('/', users.userController);
    next();
}
```

main handler logic is

```
exports.indexController = function (req, res) {
...
    return res.json(response);
}

exports.questionController = function (req, res) {
...
    return res.json(response);
}

exports.userController = function (req, res) {
...
    return res.json(response);
}
```

When I send any request, I get a `404` though. Why?

Comment: The request `GET /questions` will be matched by the first middleware (`app.use('/', ...)`) and if that replies with 404, that's it. Put the shorter paths after the longer paths.